# Service Class + Instantiating new classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0, dns, ninject

I wanted to know if this was thread safe/ good practice. My IOC is ninject, everything service layer call is via the default setting (In transient scope I think?).

**Question**, is instantiating `new FileAllocation(loggedonuser,_repo)` correct? The best way? What is the best way to do this? This is a domain class that holds logic that could be called from various services, there are usually a few database calls involved, most of the time no persistance is necessary...

Anyway, I call my service method via an interface e.g.

```
void SaveFile(int reportid, stream file); //Interface name: IReportFileService


public Class FileService: Servicebase, IReportFileService
{

  private readonly IRepoSession _repo;
  public FileService(IUserSession user, IRepoSession repo, IUpdateSession update)
 : base(user,update)
 {
   _repo = repo;
 }

 //save file if users 'counter' is ok..
 public void SaveFile(int reportid, stream file)
 {

  //here I want to instantiate a new class that I store in my domain and store the counters
  //etc and do related db calls to check up relevant values

  //note loggedonuser is a prop on my *base class*
  var userChecks = new FileAllocation(loggedonuser,_repo);
  userChecks.CountEmUp(); //exception is thrown if 0, less than "limit" etc...

  base.update(userChecks.mycompany); //persist
  base.commit(); //base class method includes try, catch block...

 }

}

public class FileAllocation
{

 private readonly IRepoSession _repo;
 private readonly Loggedonuser _user;
 private int CompanyUploads;
 private int UserUploads;
 public Company mycompany;

 public FileAllocation(Loggedonuser user, IRepoSession repo)
 {
  _repo = repo;
  _user = user;
 }

 public void CountEmUp()
 {
   //do error checking,
   //load up other tables can user upload - permissions, count is ok etc...
   // check the upload type if of certain type we cannot proceed - call another method on this class

   //set myCompany variable to new limits etc...

 }

}
```

Base Service includes a prop, I dont want to **instantiate** this from **other services** i.e. more that once, how do I avoid that?

```
    private LoggedonuserDTO _currentuser = null;
    protected LoggedonuserDTO loggedonuser
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentuser == null)
            {

                _currentuser = _user.GetCurrentUser(); //make db call here...
            }
            return _currentuser;
        }
    }
```

**@Darin** suggested:

```
public interface IFileAllocation
{
  CountEmUp(Loggedonuser currentuser);
}


//pass in loggedonuser to any method that requires it...
public class FileAllocation: IFileAllocation
{
  CountEmUp(Loggedonuser currentuser)
  { 
   //do whatever here...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userChecks = new FileAllocation(loggedonuser,_repo);
```

introduces a strong coupling between the `FileService` and the `FileAllocation` classes. If this is not a problem for you then you can leave it that way. Otherwise you could abstract the operations of this `FileAllocation` class into an interface and then inject it into `FileService`. This way the `FileService` is weakly coupled with `FileAllocation` and could be reused in different contexts and unit tested in isolation.

Comment: The main problem I have with this approach is, say I have instantiated loggedonuser from my base class, how can I pass this very instance onto the Ninjected Service class, this is my biggest concern...

Comment: @Haroon, I meant making `FileAllocation` implement an interface and having `FileService` take this interface as constructor argument.

Comment: so you mean, public FileService(IUserSession user, IRepoSession repo, IUpdateSession update, IFileService fileservice): base(user,update){ _repo = repo;, _fileservice = fileservice} ??? That I understand, however I am still instantiatinng, loggedonuser 2x from my base class then, should I should you how I instantiate loggedonuser from baseservice? I have updated my code...

Comment: @Haroon, you can pass the logged on user that you obtain in `FileService` as argument to some method of FileAllocation that would need it.

Comment: ok now that makes sense, then pass it onto every method in the same class that would need an instance of this? That does sound a lot better... I still wanted to avoid that but I guess its more testable this way...